# get list of deleted primary key from auto increment primary key

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table on which id is a primary key column set with auto increment. It contains over 10,00 rows.

I need to get all primary keys that have been deleted.
like

```
1 xcgh fct

2 xxml fcy

5 ccvb fcc

6 tylu cvn

9 vvbh cvv
```

The result that i should get is

```
3

4

7

8
```

currently i count all records and then insert(1 to count) in another table and then i select id from that table that dosent exists in record table. But this method is very inefficient. Is there any direct query that i can use?
please specify for mysql.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In general it's best to just leave the gaps in the auto-increment sequence alone.

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL? Please, don't tag ambiguous

Comment: I want to do this because my client dosent understand primary key and he says if my total product is less that 1000 why productno is greater than this. report section is in asp and i cant change that. And this is mysql.

Comment: So explain PKs to your client. Do NOT muck around with AUTO_INCREMENTing keys!

Comment: Auto-increments do not roll back, so if a transaction rolls back for any reason there will be a gap in series. If document needs serial numbering, auto-increment is a bad choice.

Comment: Part of the solution will likely use rank as shown in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b14f/134/1) example

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf67/4/0

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (
  id     INT  PRIMARY KEY
, mVal  VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO SomeTable
VALUES (1, 'xcgh fct'), 
       (2, 'xxml fcy'), 
       (5, 'ccvb fcc'), 
       (6, 'tylu cvn'), 
       (9, 'vvbh cvv');

set @rank = (Select max(ID)+1 from sometable);

create table CompleteIDs as (Select @rank :=@rank-1 as Rank
                             from sometable st1, sometable st2
                             where @rank >1);


SELECT   CompleteIDs.Rank 
FROM CompleteIDs
LEFT JOIN someTable S1 
  on CompleteIDs.Rank = S1.ID
WHERE S1.ID is null
order by CompleteIDs.rank
```

There is one assumption here.  That the number of records in someTable* the number of records in sometable is greater than the maximum ID in sometable.  Otherwise this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a temp table, fill it with e.g. 1,000 values, you can do it using any scripting language or try a procedure (This might be not-effective overall)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRand(IN NumRows INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    WHILE i <= NumRows DO
        INSERT INTO rand VALUES (i);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertRand(5);
```

Then you just do query

```
SELECT id AS deleted_id FROM temporary_table
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT id FROM main_table)
```

Please note that it should be like every day action or something cause it's very memory inefficient